# Running Cron every 2 weeks on saturday

Tags: linux, redhat, cron, zimbra

we have a cron job that run every Saturday at 01:00 (0 1 * * 6) we want to modified to run every 2 weeks on Saturday at 01:00.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to wrap your job in a script

```
 week=$(date +%V); if [ $(( $week % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then echo "run program"; fi
```

Then just run the wrapper every week... Change the 0 to a 1 for odd weeks..